# Is there a Microsoft (built-in) ETW Provider for tracing ETW lifecycle events?

Tags: windows, etw

I can't seem to find an ETW provider for tracing ETW lifecycle events, such as:

- when is a trace event session created (name, options)
- when is a trace event session disposed
- when is a provider enabled for a trace event session (provider name, guid, options)
- when is a provider disabled for a trace event session (provider name, guid, options)

This is self-tracing - using ETW to trace itself. I can't just make such an ETW provider, it has to have been made already by Microsoft, as the events must originate from within the Windows kernel.

Comment: what in detail do you want to trace?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have edited the title and text in order to make it more clear what I mean.

Comment: Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Evntprov/nc-evntprov-penablecallback or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/etw/queryalltraces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing` is the provider for ETW lifecycle events