# In Event Tracing for Windows (ETW), how do I use EventSource to point to Notepad and retrieve the menu item selected in an ETW Session?

Tags: c#, etw

I am trying to understand Event Tracing in Windows (ETW). What I want to do is capture which menu item was selected in Notepad. If I click Word Wrap, I want ETW to tell me this.

I have looked at the samples on GitHub.  One of the Event Producers is the demo:

```
namespace TraceEventSamples
{
    // In these demos, we generate events with System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource and read them with ETWTraceEventSource
    // 
    // Normally the EventSource and the ETWTraceEventSource would be indifferent processes, however, we 
    // don't do this here to make the scenario really easy to run.   The code works in the multi-process case, however.  
    namespace Producer
    {
        [EventSource(Name = "Microsoft-Demos-SimpleMonitor")]     // This is the name of my eventSource outside my program.  
        class MyEventSource : EventSource
        {
            // Notice that the bodies of the events follow a pattern:  WriteEvent(ID, <args>) where 
            //     ID is a unique ID starting at 1 and incrementing for each new event method. and
            //     <args> is every argument for the method.  
            // WriteEvent then takes care of all the details of actually writing out the values complete
            // with the name of the event (method name) as well as the names and types of all the parameters. 
            public void MyFirstEvent(string MyName, int MyId) { WriteEvent(1, MyName, MyId); }
            public void MySecondEvent(int MyId) { WriteEvent(2, MyId); }
            public void Stop() { WriteEvent(3); }

            // Typically you only create one EventSource and use it throughout your program.  Thus a static field makes sense.  
            public static MyEventSource Log = new MyEventSource();

            // You don't need to define this override, but it does show you when your eventSource gets commands, which
            // is helpful for debugging (you know that your EventSource got the command.  
            protected override void OnEventCommand(EventCommandEventArgs command)
            {
                EventGenerator.Out.WriteLine("EventSource Gets command {0}", command.Command);
            }

            // We could add Keyword definitions so that you could turn on some events but not others
            // but we don't do this here to keep it simple.  Thus you either turn on all events or none.  
        }
```

This is creating events for the demo, but how can I wire this to Notepad instead?  Can ETW be used for this type of logging, knowing what someone clicked on a menu of an application?

I have looked at various SO questions, but they did not help.  One generic was, [Is there a Microsoft (built-in) ETW Provider for tracing ETW lifecycle events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105897/is-there-a-microsoft-built-in-etw-provider-for-tracing-etw-lifecycle-events)

I considered this because it does not require C#, [C++ Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400899/c-event-tracing-for-windows-etw-wrapper) but didn't understand how it helped me.

This makes me think I cannot do it with managed code if I didn't write the original program:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1

What I am attempting to do is capture which menu item is selected, and take action with my program that caught the event.  The reason for this is an old VB6 program.  I cannot do what I need to do, so my last resort is to capture the menu item and get my application to do what I want.  I wanted to start with a simple notepad.exe.

VB6 user clicks "View X."  My C# application does "View Y".

Comment: the application has to rise the events. if notepad doesn't do this you can't capture anything

Comment: What would it be if it isn't an event, since it only happens if I click it?